# CPU affinity in virtualised environments

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu-cache

Is taskset for CPU affinity applicable when trying to use L2 cache efficiently on a multi core processor in a virtualised environment like Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, especially towards the smaller instances, there's heavy CPU sharing, you're dependent on what the other instances are doing with the CPU.

Comment: What about for large instances, especially cluster compute instances?

Comment: Amazon implies that you can use CPU affinity for larger cluster instances here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/01/ec2-for-in-memory-computing-the-high-memory-cluster-eight-extra-large.html